# How to use DRF OrderingFilter inside @action view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I can't find information on how to use OrderingFilter from django rest framework inside ModelViewSet `@action`, does anyone know how would i implement that?

I have categories and those categories have products that i get with that action, i want to order those products with a query string. Basically i would need to know how to use it on a queryset, but i cant find any info about that.

Example url: `http://example.com/categories/2/get_products/?ordering=price`

And here is the code, thanks for any help.

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer

    @action(detail=True)
    def get_products(self, request, pk=None):
        categories = Category.objects.get(id=pk).get_descendants(
            include_self=True).values_list('product_type__id', flat=True)

        products = Product.objects.filter(
            product_type__id__in=list(categories)
        )
        paginator = ProductPagination()
        paginated_products = paginator.paginate_queryset(products, request)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(
            paginated_products, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem and I wasn't happy with creating other view just for an action which fit perfectly inside the ViewSet, so I checked DRF code and it turns out that you just need to add one line:

```py
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter]

    @action(detail=True)
    def get_products(self, request, pk=None):
        qs = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        # rest of code inside function would use the queryset qs from above.
```

[DRF handles this](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L83) inside `GenericAPIView`. If you are using `ListModelMixin`, as in a `ModelViewSet`, you can also [check](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L33) the `list` method for serializing and pagination, cf.:

```py
class ListModelMixin:
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

EDIT: wrong links.

Comment: `@action` methods are limited, what if you want to add ordering for products? or search? or filtering by prices? You'll need to add logic for all of that (eg. copy paste from list mixin to get the pagination and serialization support) when a different api view will make it much easier with less code (look at my response).

Comment: I agree with you, however, these are not that many lines to replicate, and they can be concatenated together since the output of one is the input of the other. Also, there are a lot of people reading the code base in which I work and in my case the semantics for our views should be clear. If I have an `@action`, mainly a POST for a given `ModelViewSet` I'd very much like it to be semantically interpreted as an "action for a model", so the natural place would be there. I agree nontheless that this is not the general case and that you solution should be preferred in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest creating a different api view for products:

```
class CategoryProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
    ordering_fields = ('price', )
 
    def get_queryset(self):
        categories = Category.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['category_pk'])\
           .get_descendants(include_self=True)\
           .values_list('product_type__id', flat=True)

        return Product.objects.filter(product_type__id__in=categories)
```

And then in your routers add the url:

```
router.register(r'categories/(?P<category_pk>[0-9]+)/products', CategoryProductViewSet)
```

Going with this approach will let you benefit from everything that a normal viewset can offer.